# Passing data from database to intent

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I am getting a random value from the database in my getnum function whenever i enter a 10 digit number but when i enter a number less than 10 digits,eveything works fine.
Please tell how to pass a 10 digit number in the getnum function.

```
  public void callme(View v)
{
    Intent i= new Intent();
    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mydb.getnum(id_To_Update)));
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and this is my getnum function in MyDBHandler

```
 public Integer getnum(int id){
   int dat =0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT number FROM userdata1 where id="+id+"", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        dat = cursor.getInt(0);
    }

    return dat;
}
```

And this is how i created MyDBHandler

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ome1.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "userdata1";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "number";

public MyDBHandler(Context context)

{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(
                "create table userdata1 " +
                        "(id integer primary key, name text,email text,amount integer,number integer)"
        );


}
```

Comment: Getting any type of execption?try it using `long` instead of `int`

Comment: Yes, long did the trick....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changed int to long in the above code,i.e

```
public Long getnum(int id){
    Long dat=null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT number FROM userdata1 where id="+id+"", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        dat = cursor.getLong(0);
    }
```